# bitbucket pipelines scheduled deploy from specific commit

Tags: bitbucket-pipelines

Im looking to schedule a build of a repo but from the last production deployment.

I can see im able to create schedule from a particular branch but the branch we need may be beyond the currently deployed version and what we'd like is to simply rerun what was already deployed to a specific environment from that branch.

Is this possible? Im having some trouble finding instructions on how I can do this as a scheduled run.

Thanks

Comment: Make a branch that is kept that at point and make that be scheduled

Answer (score 0):

As part of your deployment script, move a git branch to the commit being deployed. Then you can schedule the custom pipeline on that branch.

```
definitions:
  yaml-anchors:
    - &deploy-step
        clone:
          depth: ????
        script:
          - git branch --force release/$BITBUCKET_DEPLOYMENT_ENVIRONMENT
          - git push origin release/$BITBUCKET_DEPLOYMENT_ENVIRONMENT
          - ...
       

pipelines:
  custom:
    your-thing:
      - step:
          script: []
      
  branches:
    main:
      - step:
          <<: *deploy-step
          name: Deploy Test
          deployment: test
          trigger: automatic
      - step:
          <<: *deploy-step
          name: Deploy Production
          deployment: production
          trigger: manual
```

You may need to tune cloning options or write a preamble fetching git references and commits because a shallow clone might not cut it.